# How can I return API Messages in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have some message in the API response. I want to return the message to user. I cannot find how can I do it.

Sample Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> ListCountries()
{
    List<Country> countries = new List<Country>();
    var response = await _client.GetAsync("countries/getall");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var JsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonCountryData>(apiResponse);
        countries = JsonData.Data;
    }
    return View(countries);
}
```

Country Model

```
namespace EVisaProject.Models
{
    public class CountryModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
    }

    public class JsonCountryData
    {
        public List<CountryModel> Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

API

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  How is the data in the image related to the code shown?  Is that the structure of `JsonCountryData` that's being received?  In the code you are explicitly ignoring any other fields on that object and sending only `countries` to the view.  If you want to send the entire object to the view, what stops you from doing that?  What specifically isn't working as expected in your code?

Comment: The image is example API return. Not related with controller. I can reach the data but I cannot reach message. I want to learn how can return the message?

Comment: `JsonData.Message` ?  Where is your `JsonData` class and what properties does it de-serialize?  You'd "reach the `message`" property exactly like you already "reach the `data`" property.  It's still not clear what you've tried and what isn't working as expected.

Comment: I edited the question. I cannot reach like you say. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't use `Json` in the names of classes, properties or variables unless you specifically dealing with JSON serialisation/deserialisation (which you are not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not de-serializing the property.  Look at the object you're de-serializing the JSON data into:

```
public class JsonCountryData
{
    public List<CountryModel> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that it contains a property called `Data`.  Which is why you can access the `Data` property.  You can't access the `Success` or `Message` properties because you haven't added them to the model, so they don't exist.

In order to use them, add them to the model so they exist:

```
public class JsonCountryData
{
    public List<CountryModel> Data { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Once they *exist*, you'll be able to use them:

```
var JsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonCountryData>(apiResponse);
// after here you can access the "Success" and "Message" properties on the "JsonData" object
```

There's nothing special about the "message" property in the JSON response.  You would access it exactly the same way that you already access the "data" property.

Comment: Thank you. You did very big thing for me.